# How to download Excel Sheet from server?

Tags: c#, excel

I have a button and when the user clicks the button it generates an excel file with 10 sheets and saves in my local folder. Then I'm downloading it.

But now they are uploading the code to the server,so the code runs in the server.How can I download the excel file from server to local disk

This is my code for downloading

```
FileStream sourceFile = null;
Response.ContentType = "application/xml"; Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(excelPath));
sourceFile = new FileStream(excelPath, FileMode.Open);
long FileSize; FileSize = sourceFile.Length;
byte[] getContent = new byte[(int)FileSize];
sourceFile.Read(getContent, 0, (int)sourceFile.Length); sourceFile.Close();
Response.BinaryWrite(getContent);
```

Here excel path refers to "F:\Customerdata.xls", after uploaded in the server I don't know where the path is going to be,So how can get that path and download it.

Comment: I'm asking how to get the server path of the saved file to download

Comment: Check up updated question @CodeCaster

Comment: See I'm giving the path as "F:\ExcelData\Customerdata.xls" as I working on my local path.When I give it to the manager, he uploads to the server,.When it runs in the server how can I get the path of that server so I can download it @CodeCaste

Comment: I want to show the user it is downloading by opening the new tab and closing it after completion.Do u know how it can be achieved @CodeCaster

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your path is "F:\ExcelData\Customerdata.xls"

Now create a virtual directory in IIS pointing to "F:\ExcelData"

You can download the file like "http:\YourURL\Customerdata.xls"

Comment: How can I created in IIS do assist me in this @Aashish